# How to edit grails column?

Tags: mysql, grails, groovy

I need some conceptual answers.
In my grail application, I need to edit a column from a list view. The problem is that the column item(for instance an author)is linked to another domain(employee)class. So in order to edit the 'author' I have to edit 'employee' (just to clarify all author are from employee class) in the table. Not sure how I can search/get an employee from the list of employee in the column to replace an author.
I know in general I can edit any page, but this look somewhat different. 
I am relatively new to groovy-grails.

Comment: it will be easy to understand me if you provide problem related snapshot or image and notify what you want or need to edit....thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML table to retrieve list as below code

```
<table>  
 <thead>
    <tr>
       <g:sortableColumn property="id" title="ID" />
       <g:sortableColumn property="author" title="Author" params="${filterParams}"/>    
    </tr>  
 </thead>  
 <tbody>    
    <g:each in="${EmployeeList}" status="i" var="employee">
      <tr class="${(i % 2) == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}">
        <td><g:link action="show" controller="employee" id="${employee.id}">${fieldValue(bean: employee, field: "id")}</g:link></td>
        <td>${fieldValue(bean: employee, field: "author")}</td>
      </tr>    
    </g:each>  
 </tbody> 
</table>
```

And for searching you may use [DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Comment: If everything above is as it is.Additionally-What if the "author" item is from different domain class? So, there are two domain class employee & books, a field "author" from books is linked to employee. Thanks @Syed Sarek

Comment: You can use two domain class by 'belongsTo'. Have a look on it http://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html